# ora-02393 exceed limit on call cpu usage (Oracle) - how to workaround

Tags: oracle

I have function which calcs the IRR (Internal Rate of Return) for specific contract ..

This function is called inside simple procedure and is applied to all contracts in defined table ..

problem is, that there is a roughly 200k rows which needs to be updated .. and the function calc_IRR() is not so effective (loop and sub-loop), which is necessary to calc the correct value ..

After an hour of run, query will exceed the CALL CPU USAGE limit (ora-02393) and the query ends.. but I need to re-run the query again ...

Here comes the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_set_irr ( p_table_name IN VARCHAR2, p_cashflow_column IN VARCHAR2, p_dimension IN VARCHAR2, p_irr_column IN VARCHAR2 )  
IS

   v_data VARCHAR2(2000);
   v_updt VARCHAR2(2000);
   v_condition VARCHAR2(2000);
   v_irr NUMBER;
   c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN  
    -- fetch each dimension data separately
    OPEN c1 FOR 'SELECT distinct '||p_dimension||' FROM '||p_table_name||' WHERE 1=1 AND '||p_irr_column||' IS NULL'; 

    LOOP  

      FETCH c1 INTO v_data;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;   

            v_condition := p_dimension || ' = ' || v_data; -- build condition for IRR calculation

            v_irr := f_calc_irr(p_table_name, p_cashflow_column, v_condition)*100;   -- calc IRR for defined contract      

            v_updt := 'UPDATE '||p_table_name||' SET '||p_irr_column||' = :1 WHERE '||p_dimension||' = :2'; -- build UDPATE query for contract

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_updt USING v_irr, v_data; -- update contract with IRR

            COMMIT;

    END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

END proc_set_irr;
/
```

How to do it without manual input of user? I have it in PACKAGE so it's called automatically once a month ...

Comment: All you can do is try and optimise this package (or more likely package ap_it.f_calc_irr) to not use too much CPU. Or if that is not possible due to your database structure you need to raise the issue higher. If you explain the logic further maybe we can help optimise. It looks like you have a schema with column names saved into config tables which is always a pain. Is there a reason this can't be done using a set based approach?

Comment: Is this the IRR calc? http://www.investopedia.com/walkthrough/corporate-finance/4/npv-irr/internal-rate-return.aspx It looks like a straight linear calculation to me but I could be wrong as I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: hmmm this makes it look much more complicated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return. There may or may not be a set based solution to this but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes, it is that IRR calc.... I am not using config tables.. I am just parsing it ... to make it more flexible for other use ...

Comment: is there any way how release the "already used CPU" and start again without interrupting the query? something like 
`if(query.runtime() >= 40min){
release.cpuUsage();
}`
or
`if(query.updatedRows() >= 100){
release.cpuUsage();
}`

Comment: I can't find any info on how the CPU usage is actually calculated. You could try liberally sprinkling `dbms_lock.sleep(1);` throughout `f_calc_irr` but its a hack. The fact is your package is CPU intensive. You should find the person who needs the result of this calculation and ask him to buy some more CPU's for your Oracle server. I bet that's cheaper than not getting the results they require. Unless your package can be rewritten to be more efficient but no ones here knows the answer to that.

Comment: I have one idea.. because the table I am updating contains multiple rows of each contract number..and because I am getting the data via SELECT DISTINCT contract_number FROM table WHERE irr = NULL (for those who are not set yet)

Comment: If you want to explain your tables in more detail and also post the contents of the function perhaps I can suggest something otherwise I can't help any further. It kind of seems like a bit of Oracle DBA snobbery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the procedure from row-by-row to a single SQL statement.  This type of conversion can often improve performance dramatically as it decreases the number of context switches between SQL and PL/SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_set_irr (
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
    p_cashflow_column IN VARCHAR2,
    p_dimension IN VARCHAR2,
    p_irr_column IN VARCHAR2
) is
begin
    execute immediate replace(replace(replace(replace(
        q'[
            merge into #P_TABLE_NAME
            using
            (
                select distinct #P_DIMENSION
                from #P_TABLE_NAME
                where #P_IRR_COLUMN is null
            ) null_irr
                on (null_irr.#P_DIMENSION = #P_TABLE_NAME.#P_DIMENSION)
            when matched then update set 
                #P_IRR_COLUMN = f_calc_irr(
                    '#P_TABLE_NAME',
                    '#P_CASHFLOW_COLUMN',
                    '#P_DIMENSION = '||null_irr.#P_DIMENSION)*100
        ]'
        , '#P_TABLE_NAME', p_table_name)
        , '#P_DIMENSION', p_dimension)
        , '#P_IRR_COLUMN', p_irr_column)
        , '#P_CASHFLOW_COLUMN', p_cashflow_column
    );

    commit;
end proc_set_irr;
/
```

There are a few other minor changes:

1. Change the UPDATE into a MERGE to avoid joining twice (once for condition, once for value).
2. Change the string concatenation to a template using the alternative quoting mechanism and `REPLACE`.  This helps reduce the number of quotation marks but it's still a bit messy.
3. Removed the exception handler.  Catching and raising is pointless unless the code either handles the error somehow or adds debug information.  The default error message contains more information than in the custom `RAISE_APPLICATION`.

Comment: hello, it doesn't count properly :( because i guess it is not parsing the #P_DIMENSION# from USING clause properly ... in final funcion f_calc_irr() if there is an error, it will return 99999 .. and all rows are updated with this value .. not the proper one.. can you please advice?

Comment: @Mr.P Woops I messed up some of the variable characters.  I changed it, try it now.

Comment: thanks for reaction .. I fixed it already ... but the problem is, that the final function (f_calc_irr) doesn't count (UPDATE) properly .. but when I try to use only the function (as SELECT f_calc_irr(....) FROM DUAL) in works ok ... where could be the problem?

Comment: @Mr.P I'm not sure, that seems like an odd problem.  We'd probably need to see that function and some sample data to debug it further.  If you replace the entire function with a static like return value, does it work the same in both contexts?